# Cross dag data exchange using Xcom

Tags: airflow

can We use Xcom to exchange data between two different Dags? So that My second dag should get the value from latest job of first Dag.

So that My second dag should get the value from latest job of first Dag

If not what is the process to data exchange.

Answer (score 1):

On xcom.pull you can define dag_id and taksids. Which mean you can pull from many tasks in the same dag at one request.

Another option (if that the case here), that always dag2 runs after dag1 then you can trigger dage from dag1 and pass it in the conf.